# Unexpected behavior while running test coverage for 2GP package

Tags: 2gp

I have created my application in developer Org and all tests run properly. While creating a 2GP package (beta) without using --code-coverage, the package is creating properly.
In order to promote it, I am now trying to create package version using *--code-coverage* parameter. I see that the tests are failing and most of them are saying:

1. *System.QueryException: No such column 'Custom_Field__c' on entity 'namespace__Custom_Object__c'* - The field and required permissions are there at profile level and Permission set level as well.
2. In test data setup, when querying custom profiles (part of package), not getting the profile in result and hence cannot run test with specific persona.

Can anyone help with these issues? I looked up on internet for similar problem, but couldn't find any solution or approach.